# Changing fragment using bottom NAV bar using fragment activity in a library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I start a new Android project with a bottom NAV bar in the mainactivity in the app module as in the picture. I plan to set the initial fragment in the featuretab1 module.

I found way to change activity using intent and setting the dependency. Just want to confirm, to change the fragment, just need to put below coding.

```
//Java in featuretab1
public class featuretab1fragment extend fragment {

    //fragment detail

}

//navbar.setOnClicklistener action in app module main activty
Fragment f = new featuretab1fragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, f);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.commit();
```

Is it what i need to do?

[image: want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` for compatibility across devices lower than API 14. Check the official docs before asking this question. Here is the link to it: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#java

```
Fragment newFragment = new featuretab1fragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Since you are just starting out with Android development, I would recommend you to learn Kotlin or Flutter instead. Both are better than Java in terms of making Android apps. Kotlin requires less code to do the same thing as what Java does and it has null safety. Flutter can create both android and ios apps at the same time with a single codebase. Flutter uses the dart programming language.